# C# Class to generate JSON collection

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I'd like to have the following class definitions:

```
[Serializable]
[CollectionDataContract(Name = "Crowd")]
public class Crowd : List<Person>
{
}

[DataContract(Name = "Person")]
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
}
```

And get the following JSON:

```
{
    [

    {"Name" : "Larry", "Age" : "42", "Gender" : "M"},
    {"Name" : "Steve", "Age" : "32", "Gender" : "M"},
    {"Name" : "Nancy", "Age" : "22", "Gender" : "F"},

    ]
}
```

But what I want to end up getting is this:

```
{
    "Crowd" : 
    [
        {"Name" : "Larry", "Age" : "42", "Gender" : "M"},
        {"Name" : "Steve", "Age" : "32", "Gender" : "M"},
        {"Name" : "Nancy", "Age" : "22", "Gender" : "F"},
    ]
}
```

It seems that the `DataContractJsonSerializer` class ignores the `[CollectionDataContract(Name = "Crowd")]` attributes. The XML serialize works as expected.

This will work but I DON'T want to define my classes like this (removed class attributes to show structure):

```
public class Root 
{    
    public List<Person> Crowd { get; set;} 
}

public class Person 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; } 
}
```

Any reason as to why .NET `DataContractJsonSerializer` ignores the `CollectionDataContract` attributes. Any ideas how I can force this to generate what I want? The XML serializer works fine but we need to use JSON.

**EDIT:** So given the input thus far, it seems this is what I should generate for my JSON (which seems very reasonable):

```
{ 
  "Crowd" :{
    "Person" : 
    [
        {"Name" : "Larry", "Age" : "42", "Gender" : "M"},
        {"Name" : "Steve", "Age" : "32", "Gender" : "M"},
        {"Name" : "Nancy", "Age" : "22", "Gender" : "F"},
    ]
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not getting the output you want because it wouldn't be valid JSON.  See [JSON.org](http://www.json.org/).  A JSON object (denoted by curly braces) is a collection of name-value pairs.  It cannot contain unnamed content.

If you put all of your persons into a `List<Person>` and serialize that directly, you can get the following output, which is valid JSON:

```
[
    {"Name" : "Larry", "Age" : "42", "Gender" : "M"},
    {"Name" : "Steve", "Age" : "32", "Gender" : "M"},
    {"Name" : "Nancy", "Age" : "22", "Gender" : "F"},
]
```

Example code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Person> list = new List<Person>
        {
            new Person {Name = "Larry", Age = "42", Gender = "M"},
            new Person {Name = "Steve", Age = "32", Gender = "M"},
            new Person {Name = "Nancy", Age = "22", Gender = "F"},
        };

        DataContractJsonSerializer ser = 
            new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<Person>));
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        ser.WriteObject(ms, list);

        ms.Position = 0;
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms);
        Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd());
    }
}

[DataContract]
public class Person
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Age { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Gender { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Brian. I edited my question given your answer by noting the alternative JSON I should be using. Didn't realize it wasn't a valid JSON object I wanted to generate. Given this new JSON, I had issues using a generic list and the noted serializer to get the JSON I wanted.  What I get is a root named after the generic list class and not named after my derived class.

class Crowd : List<People>

.NET seems to ignore the CollectionDataContract attributes. Any ideas?

Comment: Generally, your class structure needs to match the JSON output you desire.  Thus if you want your JSON to have a root object containing a property called "Crowd" which is an array containing Person objects, you will need to provide a root class containing a member called "Crowd".  Since you said in your question you didn't want to do this, the only alternative I can think of is to switch to a different serializer.  If you use Json.Net you can make a custom JsonConverter to do what you want.  A converter allows the class structure to differ from the JSON.

Comment: Thanks again Brian. I appreciate your input and time on this topic. I am going to go with what you initially recommended for my JSON output.

Comment: No problem.  Good luck on your project.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike XML which needs a root element, JSON does not need a root element. The whole JSON itself is the root element and hence does not generate the JSON that you are looking for.

The JSON you desire is equivalent to having a JSON object with a property "Crowd" that is an array of people. However, that is not how your code is represented. When you serialize a `Crowd` object, it is just an Array of Persons and that is what the serializer creates. If you really do need the "Crowd" property name, then there is no option but to create a wrapper class `Root` as you have done.

Comment: Thanks RKam. My research also points in that direction. It's strange that JSON doesn't need a root element and given my current output, it seems that the collection doesn't have a type attribute, just a bunch of repeated columns without a 'root' name to tie them all together. If someone was to get that collection, it could be any number of things, like "criminals", "teachers", "managers", etc.

Thanks again for your input on this topic.

Comment: It becomes semantic when you tie the fact that JSON is the way to denote Javascript objects. What you are denoting in JSON is an Array object and it would be sub-optimal to represent the children by another property. Javascript doesn't support object orientation natively and hence everything is an object. Think of it as serializing a .NET dynamic object. If you so wish to serialize the type, you should include a property that shows the type. Examples are frameworks like BreezeJS which do that when serializing data from .NET to Javascript.